# CLLocationManager and iPad Settings - missing app in Settings

Tags: ios, ipad, settings, location, cllocation

I recently had an ipad app approved by Apple and made available on the App Store. I mention this because my app uses location services and implements all of the practices outlined by Apple. And I'm also assuming that Apple tested all of those scenarios with my app before approving it.

Shortly after approval I started receiving bug reports in which users that had location services turned Off were  correctly prompted to enable location services - by my app - but when they go into the Settings app and "enable" location services, there is no entry or registration for my app. And of course my app checks for both globally enabled location services and then it's app level location services settings.

I've been unable to reproduce this bug on ipads running both ios 4.2 and 4.3. I've googled for a few hours and didn't turn up much. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions. I'm off the reservation on this one. Shoot - I can't even reproduce it.

Thanks for any help.

***UPDATE***

I found the answer:

In order to have your application registered in the Location Service settings your app must make a call to CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation. If the user has not turned on Location Services the didFailWithError delegate will get called and the app can handle the scenario accordingly.

Comment: This should be marked as answered. At the moment it appears in the unanswered list which some people read through to see if they can help